# How capture 5 thumbnail from frames 1,25%,50%,75%,100% of video with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, thumbnails

I want capture five thumbnail from 5 points of a video with same distance from each other like 1,25%,50%,75%,100%

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to get video duraiton.

```
ffmpeg -i file.flv 2>&1 | grep "Duration"
```

Result of above command something like this
 Duration: 00:12:43.08, start: 0.040000, bitrate: 386 kb/s

Then you should calculate 1%,25%,50%,75%,100% of video duration and you convert them to `00:00:00.000`

Last you can run thumbnail command something like this.

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv -ss 00:00:11.435 -vframes 1 out.png
```

Example:
if duration of your video is 00:10:00.000, that means it is 600 seconds so

```
600 * 1 / 100 = 6 => 00:00:06.000
600 * 25 / 100 = 150 => 00:02:30.000
600 * 50 / 100 = 300 => 00:05:00.000
600 * 75 / 100 => 450 => 00:07:30.000
600 * 100 / 100 => 600 => 00:10:00.000
```

Finally you can get thumbnails by following commands

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv -ss 00:00:06.000 -vframes 1 out1.png
ffmpeg -i input.flv -ss 00:02:30.000 -vframes 1 out2.png
ffmpeg -i input.flv -ss 00:05:00.000 -vframes 1 out3.png
ffmpeg -i input.flv -ss 00:07:30.000 -vframes 1 out4.png
ffmpeg -i input.flv -ss 00:10:00.000 -vframes 1 out5.png
```

Comment: Don't parse the output from `ffmpeg`: it is not meant for machine processing. [Use `ffprobe` instead](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips#Duration).

Comment: I'm looking for a command that handle all of this in one ffmpeg command like using video filters